# Vue component not re rendering on new $router.push

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have this SearchResult component which when invoked by vue-router, fetches an object from YouTube API v3 passes the recieved object as props to dozens of child components. I have a search bar which uses `$router.push(/search/ + this.query)` to change routes and display this component.

The problem is that it works great for the first time or when I'm using search from some other route. But when I search again the component **doesn't** re-renders with new results from the API. Even though I've added a watcher for `this.$route.params.query`. Here is SearchResult.vue component.

```
<template>
<div>
  <app-banner></app-banner>
  <div v-if="resultIds">
    <div v-for="resId in resultIds.items">
      <vid-preview :vidId="resId.id.videoId"></vid-preview>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      resultIds: null,
      errors: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.params.query' (newQuery, oldQuery) {
      this.$router.push('/search/' + newQuery) //This code executes but no change visible on screen.
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/`, {
      params: {
        part: 'id',
        q: this.$route.params.query,
        order: 'relevance',
        maxResults: '50',
        key: '{API KEY}'
      }
    }).then(res => {
      this.resultIds = res.data;
    }).catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e);
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this :

```
'$route.params.query' (newQuery, oldQuery) {
  this.$router.push({
    path: '/search/' + newQuery
  })
}
```

currently :

```
'$route.params.query' (newQuery, oldQuery) {
  this.$router.push('/search/' + newQuery) //This code executes but no change visible on screen.
}
```

Comment: @samayo thanks for edit, i was trying to make it like code :)

Comment: No problems. Next time highlight your block of code and click `{}` from the editor tools

Comment: Shouldn't $route.params.query in single quotes??

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working for me, unfortunately. The component is still not re-rendering.

Comment: problem maybe this.$router is not working, try to console.log(this) and see if it returns the vue instance

Comment: Yeah It does return the vue instance: `VueComponent {_uid: 2, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}`

Comment: checked on my local works fine, did you checked the search query route if problem there ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158421/discussion-between-mandeep-gill-and-edward-mckinzie).

Comment: @MandeepGill, May i ask you to have a look at a Vue.JS question related with the source code in github of the book 'Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5' by Anthone Gore here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245577/laravel-vuejs-router-view-does-not-render-the-component ? Particularly take a look at the EDIT: section of the OP

Comment: your "solution" is just another way to do the same thing with the same result