# Laravel VueJs : `router-view` does not render the component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

**I know such questions are out there in this site but they do not solve my problem. Hence this question pops up here :**

In my Laravel 5.3 and VueJs app, the root instance of Vue in  `app.js` file points to `App.vue` and in `App.vue` I have the `router-view` placeholder. So I expect page components to be rendered inside the placeholder but that does not happen.

Let me show the contents in different files:

In `web.php` I have :

```
Route::get('/listing/{listing}', function(Listing $listing){

    $model = $listing->toArray();

    return view('app',['model' => $model]);


});
```

In `router.js`, I have :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import ListingPage from '../components/ListingPage';

Vue.use(VueRouter);


    export default new VueRouter({
        mode:'history',
        routes:[

            { path: '/listing/:listing', component: ListingPage, name: 'listing' }
        ]

    });
```

In `app.js` I have :

```
import ListingPage from '../components/ListingPage.vue';
import  router  from './router';
import App from '../components/App.vue';

var app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
    router

});
```

So when I hit the url `/listing/5`, the application goes to `App.vue` and is supposed to render the `ListingPage` component inside `router-view` placeholder.

In `App.vue`, I have :

```
<template>
    <div>

        <div id="toolbar">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">
                <img class="icon" src="/images/logo.png">
                <h1>vuebnb</h1>
            </router-link>
        </div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

In `ListingPage.vue`, I have :

```
  <template>
        <div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">
                    Heading from listing page 
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="about">
                    <h3>About this listing page</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
    </template>

<script>

export default {

           data() {
               return {
                   index: 1
                     }
                  }
          }
</script>
```

But finally I only get the content in `App.vue` without the `ListingPage` component being rendered inside the placeholder.

How can I get the proper rendering there ?

**EDIT:**

Actually this questions arises out of the source code of the book '[Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/full-stack-vuejs-2-and-laravel-5)' by Anthony Gore. The source code is available at github [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Full-Stack-Vue.js-2-and-Laravel-5) . I tried to run the codebase at Chapter07. Of course I ran the necessary commands such as  `composer install, npm install, npm run dev` in `localhost` with **Laravel 5.5.6 version** but finally when I hit any URL like `/listing/5`, I do not see any content rendered from `ListingPage` component.

You can take the code from github or you may download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13HhTlcUZR-Xc8_M69VfqZf35WqVUor_O) to run in your localhost.

What might be the reason that it does not work and the potential solution as well ?

Comment: I take it you are using vuejs in development mode and there are no errors shown in the browser console?

Comment: @JaromandaX,  no errors  found.

Comment: @JaromandaX, can you have a look at the 'Edit' section I added in OP? You can  run the code from the link I provided in your `localhost` to point out the problem .

Comment: `You can run the code from the link I provided in your localhost` - my localhost doesn't have a http server .... does yours?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I ran XAMPP from here : https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html  to create the http server in my PC. My PHP version is 7.1.26 and Laravel version is 5.5.26

Comment: The code you're posting looks fine. Here's where to look to narrow down on the issue: check the JavaScript console for errors, check Vue Devtools and see if the router-view component is present and if the ListingPage component is present. Also, try replacing ListingPage with some simple component and see if it renders.

Comment: @anthonygore, There was a glitch.. I did bot run the command `php artisan serve`. Rather  I just hit the browser URL. But the amazing thing is that console showed no error. So 1) When is it necessary to run the mentioned command ? 2) Can you give an answer to a related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289548/laravel-vuejs-building-multi-page-app-without-resorting-to-single-page-applicat ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed best to look up the docs for the artisan serve command, as it is an unrelated concept to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your base path in touter config like this :

```
export default new VueRouter({
  mode:'history',
  routes:[

    { path: '/:listing', component: ListingPage, name: 'listing' }
  ],
  base:'/listing',
  root:'/',

});
```

Comment: why to declare `base` and `root` ?

Comment: because you need to declare what is the url  should router work on it

Comment: have you tryed it?

Comment: Have a look at the 'EDIT:' section I added in OP. Can you run the code from the link I provided to point out the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that inside of 
`"render: h => h(App)"` you can use

```
components: {App},
template: '<App></App>'
```

Then the app.js code will be like:

```
import  router  from './router';
import App from '../components/App.vue';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {App},
    template: '<App></App>',
    router
});
```

I hope that works.

best regards!